# SSIS expression building

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

I was going to specify a path

**Path is:**  C:\table_name.txt

where the portion 'table_name' is dynamic and I will retrieve the value from variable.

What I tried in expression builder is:- 
"C:\"+@[User::TableName]+".txt"

But,it gave error

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your backslash is an escaping character, which means that the expression builder treats the next character as a string literal.  This means your expression considers all of `C:\"+[User::TableName]+` to be the first string and anything afterwards (`.txt"`) to be expression operators.

In short, you need to escape your escaping character so that it doesn't escape your double quote:

`"C:\\"+[User::TableName]+".txt"`